# ajax - Submitting multiple buttons with AJAX but getting first value only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue where I am trying to pass a submit buttons values along with the form to ajax but for some reason the only value that passes no matter which button I push is the first button. There is more to the form but I am just showing the buttons.

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name"finalize_invoice" id="finalize_invoice" value="Delete" />
    <input type="submit" name"finalize_invoice" id="finalize_invoice" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" name"finalize_invoice" id="finalize_invoice" value="Finalize" />
</form>
```

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form#submit").submit(function() {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            var invoice_temp_id = $('#invoice_temp_id').attr('value');
            var man_part_number = $('#man_part_number').attr('value');
            var customer = $('#customer').attr('value');
            var date = $('#date').attr('value');
            var shipdate = $('#shipdate').attr('value');
            var shipvia = $('#shipvia').attr('value');
            var ponumber = $('#ponumber').attr('value');
            var rep = $('#rep').attr('value');
            var invoicenotes = $('#invoicenotes').attr('value');
            var serial_number = $('#serial_number').attr('value');
            var skid = $('#skid').attr('value');
            var finalize_invoice = $('#finalize_invoice').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/createfinalinvoice.php?",
            data: "invoice_temp_id="+ invoice_temp_id+
                "&man_part_number="+ man_part_number+
                "&customer="+ customer+
                "&date="+ date+
                "&shipdate="+ shipdate+
                "&shipvia="+ shipvia+
                "&ponumber="+ ponumber+
                "&rep="+ rep+
                "&invoicenotes="+ invoicenotes+
                "&serial_number="+ serial_number+
                "&skid="+ skid+
                "&finalize_invoice="+ finalize_invoice+
                $( this ).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    if (data == 1) {
                        var thiserror = 'You may not have any blank fields, please make sure there is a serial number in each field';
                        alert(thiserror);
                    }
                    if (data == 2) {
                        var thiserror = 'Your serial number(s) do not match with the Manufacture Part Numbers, please double check your list';
                        alert(thiserror);
                    }
                    if (data == 3) {
                        var thiserror = 'Some of your serial numbers are not located in the database, please make sure you entered the correct serial number';
                        alert(thiserror);
                    }
                    if (data == 4) {
                        var thiserror = 'This item has already been sold to another customer. Please report this to administration';
                        alert(thiserror);
                    }
                    if (data == 5) {
                        var thiserror = 'Everything went OK, you may continue and view the processed invoice';
                        alert(thiserror);
                    }
                    if (data == 6) {
                        var thiserror = 'There are no default prices setup for this customer matching the Manufacture Part Numbers. Please check and make sure they all exist before processing this list';
                        alert(thiserror);
                    }
                    if (data == 7) {
                        window.location = ('/admin/?mmcustomers=1&viewinvoice=1');
                    }

                }
            });
            return false;
            });
         });
```

Comment: I am using "$( this ).serialize()," in the code if you notice. Do I not have to send each value manually as well if I do that?

Comment: I removed my first comment, because it wasn't an answer to your question, however, using .serialize() will collect all the data from the form so (indeed) you won't have to collect all data by hand. (see http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ for an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three `submit` buttons with identical `id`s of `finalize_invoice`. `id`s must be unique however. This is the reason, jquery selects the first button only, no matter which one was clicked. If you want to send the request with the clicked button, bind a function to the `button`'s click event

```
$('form#submit input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    ...
    var finalize_invoice = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax(...);
    ...
    return false;
}
```

As @thaJeztah suggested, suppressing the submit event on `form`

```
$('form#submit').submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This looks like a proper solution to me, however, it would be wise to add an event-handler for the 'submit' event that cancels regular form-submits. (e.g. to prevent the form being submitted a user presses 'enter' in an input-field; in which case form will be submitted without a button being clicked). This will *also* happen if the user has javascript disabled, which may be a problem if you rely on the value of the 'button' clicked

Comment: @thaJeztah Thank you, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="button" name"del_button" id="del_btn" value="Delete" />
    <input type="button" name"save_button" id="save_btn" value="Save" />
    <input type="button" name"finalize_button" id="finalize_btn" value="Finalize" />
</form> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var clicked_btn = '';
        $('form').submit(function(){ return false; });
        $('form input[type=button]').click(function(){ 
             clicked_btn = $(this).attr('id'); 
             yourSubmitFunction(clicked_btn); 
             return false; 
        });
    }
</script>
```